# Is there a way to use NPM packages in Android project with Kotlin

Tags: javascript, android, kotlin

I was wondering if there is a way to use NPM packages in Android project with Kotlin. I know there is a Gradle plugin `kotlin.js` and it seems to work with a standalone project like [a demo](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-js-demo-1.3.50/blob/master/build.gradle.kts) provided by JetBrains, but when I try to use it with Android I get this error:

```
Cannot add extension with name 'kotlin', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
```

There is even a little [tutorial](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-project-setup.html) on how to setup kotlin/js, also provided by JetBrains, but there is nothing new.

I'm asking because I want to start a little multiplatform project, but the core part of it is a library, which I had written some time ago, but it is in Java, and it is heavily dependant on `BouncyCastle` and some other libraries that handles XML serialization, so there is no luck with that. But I found a similar library in JavaScript. And since I can not use any Java dependency with `kotlin/multiplatform` there are two options for me, either find a way to make Kotlin/JS work with Android project or move on to React-Native, which I like, but I would prefer Kotlin.

Comment: "And since I can not use any Java dependency with kotlin/multiplatform" -- yes you can. Otherwise, you would be unable to write any Android app using Kotlin/Multiplatform, since the Android SDK is a Java dependency. Your Kotlin/Common module(s) cannot use the Java dependency, but they can use `expect` to allow for platform-specific modules to supply `actual` implementations. Your Android app could use the Java dependency, while any Kotlin/JS modules could use the NPM dependency, each wrapped in your own code to provide a standard API to your Kotlin/Common module(s).

Comment: But, in answer to your question, AFAIK you cannot use an NPM module in Android just via Kotlin/Multiplatform. Kotlin/JS does not target Android, and Kotlin/JVM does not support JavaScript libraries (NPM or otherwise). It's possible that you could find a JavaScript interpreter (e.g., duktape) that could use your NPM module inside of a Kotlin/JVM project.

Comment: @CommonsWare So, are you saying that I can use pure java library with kotlin/multiplatform and use it as a shared code (possibly with Kotlin wrapper) between Android and iOS apps? Because I thought you could not use Java, because of bytecode.

Comment: No. I am saying that you can use a Java library for Kotlin/JVM modules inside of Kotlin/Multiplatform project. And, if you want, you can wrap that Java library in Kotlin code with an `actual` declaration, so your Kotlin/Common modules can indirectly use that library. However, for any other platform, you would have to create an `actual` implementation for that platform. So, if you wrapped a Java library in Kotlin/JVM with `actual`, you would need to find a pod or something for iOS that you could wrap with `actual` for the same API. Then, your Kotlin/Common code can `expect` it.

Comment: @CommonsWare Sorry, I'm familiar with Swift, but it's a little rusty. So, if I understood it right, I can wrap Java library in Kotlin and use it as shared code, but to make it work with Swift I would need to do this => Swift(Kotlin(JavaLibrary))? Is there any example?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not know how to interpret your notation with the parentheses. Let's pretend that your Kotlin/Multiplatform project has `androidApp/`, `iosApp/`, and `common/` modules. `common/` could define an `expect` API for which both `androidApp/` and `iosApp/` would need to supply `actual` implementations. `androidApp/` could use a Java library to help with that. `iosApp/` could use some iOS library to help with that. The `common/` module does not care about those details -- it works with the `expect`-defined API

Comment: In terms of examples, you might rummage through [Touchlab's blog](https://touchlab.co/blog/) and their other Kotlin/Multiplatform resources.

Comment: @CommonsWare So, this way `common/` module is just an abstract API?

Comment: It is code that uses the abstract API defined by the `expect` classes. The `actual` classes in the platform-specific modules provide the platform-specific implementation of that abstract API.